# Spring Boot, Hibernate, Querydsl: antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

I am currently developing a data warehouse with spring boot, hibernate and querydsl. 
Nearly everything is working fine, but I got trouble doing a search request for one of my entity called `group`. The errors, are not really helpful:

My request is simple `/group/advancedSearch?page=0&size=10&sort=name,asc&search=groupCode:dfa,name:dfa,`

The errors raise in my service when I do call the repository method.

```
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: group
[...]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

To make this more understandable my code is below. I have the same method for most of my entities and there it is working fine. Because I had no clue where the `unexpected token group` might come from, I had a look at the generated class `QGroup`, there I found this peace of code `public static final QGroup group = new QGroup("group1");`. The name `group1` made me wonder, but I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the errors. In all other classes the string was always the name of the class with initial letters small.

I thought the entity `group` might be duplicated, so querydsl would create `group` and `group1`, but that's not the case. So any ideas where the errors might come from and how to prevent / fix them?

The entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "[Group]")
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Group_ID")
    private long groupId;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "Dimension_ID")
    private Dimension dimension;

    @Column(name = "Dimension_ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Long dimensionId;

    @Column(name = "GroupCode")
    private String groupCode;

    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    [...]
}
```

The function of the controller where the errors raise:

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = GROUP_URL + "/advancedSearch", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public PagedResources<Group> advancedSearch(
            @RequestParam(value = "search", required = false) String search,
            Pageable pageable, @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters,
            PersistentEntityResourceAssembler persistentEntityResourceAssembler
    ) {
        SimpleGrantedAuthority[] allowedRoles = {SYSADMIN};
        GeneralPredicateBuilder<Group> builder = new GeneralPredicateBuilder<>(Group.class);
        Predicate predicate = predicateService.getPredicateFromParameters(parameters, Group.class);
        Page<Group> results = service.advancedSearch(
                this.buildAdvancedSearch(search, predicate, builder), pageable, allowedRoles);
        return super.toPagedResource(results, persistentEntityResourceAssembler);
    }

    public Predicate buildAdvancedSearch(String search, Predicate predicate, GeneralPredicateBuilder<T> builder) {
        if (search != null) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+?)(:|<|>)(\\w+?),");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(search + ",");
            while (matcher.find()) {
                builder.with(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3));
            }
            BooleanExpression expression = builder.build();
            if (predicate != null) {
                predicate = expression.and(predicate);
            } else {
                predicate = expression;
            }
        }
        return predicate;
    }
```

The `PredicateService`:

```java
@Service
public class PredicateService {

    @Autowired
    private final QuerydslPredicateBuilder querydslPredicateBuilder;

    @Autowired
    private final QuerydslBindingsFactory querydslBindingsFactory;

    public PredicateService(QuerydslPredicateBuilder querydslPredicateBuilder, QuerydslBindingsFactory querydslBindingsFactory) {
        this.querydslPredicateBuilder = querydslPredicateBuilder;
        this.querydslBindingsFactory = querydslBindingsFactory;
    }

    public <T> Predicate getPredicateFromParameters(final MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters, Class<T> tClass) {
        TypeInformation<T> typeInformation = ClassTypeInformation.from(tClass);
        return querydslPredicateBuilder.getPredicate(typeInformation, parameters, querydslBindingsFactory.createBindingsFor(typeInformation));
    }
}
```

The service method:

```java
    public Page<Group> advancedSearch(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable, SimpleGrantedAuthority[] roles){
        if (SecurityUtils.userHasAnyRole(roles)) {
            return this.repository.findAll(predicate, pageable); // <-- here the errors raise
        } else throw new ForbiddenException(FORBIDDEN);
    }
```

The repository:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = GROUP_URL, path = GROUP_URL)
@CrossOrigin(exposedHeaders = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
public interface GroupRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Group, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Group>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Group> {
}
```

The generated class `QGroup` by querydsl:

```java
@Generated("com.querydsl.codegen.EntitySerializer")
public class QGroup extends EntityPathBase<Group> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 384278695L;

    private static final PathInits INITS = PathInits.DIRECT2;

    public static final QGroup group = new QGroup("group1"); // <-- this is confusing

    [...]
```

---

**Update**:

I finally found the generated query:

```
select group1
from Group group1
where ?1 = ?1 and lower(group.groupCode) like ?2 escape '!'
```

I think here is the problem. Form a SQL developer view, `group.groupCode` should be `group1.groupCode`. Anyone knows how to fix this?

---

**Update 2 [2020-02-14]:**

The GeneralPredicateBuilder:

```java
public class GeneralPredicateBuilder<T> {
    private List<SearchCriteria> params;
    private final Class<T> type;


    public GeneralPredicateBuilder(Class<T> type) {
        this.params = new ArrayList<>();
        this.type = type;
    }

    public GeneralPredicateBuilder<T> with(String key, String operation, Object value) {
        params.add(new SearchCriteria(key, operation, value));
        return this;
    }

    public BooleanExpression build() {
        if (params.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        List<BooleanExpression> predicates = params.stream().map(param -> {
            GeneralPredicate<T> predicate = new GeneralPredicate<T>(param, type);
            BooleanExpression tmp = predicate.getPredicate();
            return tmp;
        }).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());

        BooleanExpression result = Expressions.asBoolean(true).isTrue();
        for (BooleanExpression predicate : predicates) {
            result = result.and(predicate);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public List<Predicate> buildPredicate(){
        if (params.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        return params.stream().map(param -> {
            GeneralPredicate<T> predicate = new GeneralPredicate<>(param, type);
            return predicate.getPredicate();
        }).filter(Objects::isNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is GeneralPredicateBuilder a class within your application? Can you post the source code?

Comment: Could you create an alias on Group.class and then use it when creating predicate expression ? http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.1.0/reference/html/ch03s04.html

Comment: I agree with RMorrisey, because there is some custom logic in your `GeneralPredicateBuilder `. Without it querydsl should generate query something like `select group0_.Group_ID as id1, group0_.groupCode as groupCod2 from "Group" group0_ where group0_.groupCode=? {}`

Comment: Sorry I was on vacation, I updated the post with my code of the `GeneralPredicateBuilder` . Again, I use the class in several other controllers and it is working fine.

Comment: Are you using a [spring-boot-starter-data-jpa](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jpa-and-spring-data) starter?

Comment: yes I do use it

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand why the, by querydsl, generated classname of `Group` is `group1`, but in combination with my `GenericPredicateBuilder` and the `GenericPredicate` this leads to the inconsistent sql, as shown in the question. But I was finally able to fix this, unfortunately in a really dirty way. For completeness here is my `GeneralPredicate`:

```java
public class GeneralPredicate<T> {
    private SearchCriteria searchCriteria;
    private final Class<T> type;
    private final String variable;

    public GeneralPredicate(SearchCriteria param, Class<T> type) {
        searchCriteria = param;
        this.type = type;
        if(type.getSimpleName().equals("Group")){
            this.variable = "group1";
        } else {
            this.variable = type.getSimpleName().replaceFirst("" + type.getSimpleName().charAt(0), "" + type.getSimpleName().charAt(0)).toLowerCase();
        }
    }

    public BooleanExpression getPredicate() {
        PathBuilder<T> entityPath = new PathBuilder<T>(type, variable);

        if (isNumeric(searchCriteria.getValue().toString())) {
            NumberPath<Integer> path = entityPath.getNumber(searchCriteria.getKey(), Integer.class);
            int value = Integer.parseInt(searchCriteria.getValue().toString());
            switch (searchCriteria.getOperation()) {
                case ":":
                    return path.eq(value);
                case ">":
                    return path.goe(value);
                case "<":
                    return path.loe(value);
            }
        } else {
            StringPath path = entityPath.getString(searchCriteria.getKey());
            switch (searchCriteria.getOperation()) {
                case ":":
                    return path.containsIgnoreCase(searchCriteria.getValue().toString());
                case "<":
                    return path.startsWith(searchCriteria.getValue().toString());
                case ">":
                    return path.endsWith(searchCriteria.getValue().toString());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

You find the dirty fix within the constructor. I really hate it, but it is working and the generated sql is okay.

Maybe I use the generic in a wrong way. I am open for advices.